# Adding a picture during signup using amazon cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In signup page for my web applicatin I want to make picture mandatory along with other attributes like email, name etc. When a user clicks submit button in my web application i am calling SignUp API by AWS but the aws cognito api for signup just takes the path of the picture. As per this thread ( https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=243794)
I should first save the picture in S3 and then pass the S3's picture url into signup API but my doubt is how can I upload the picture first and then get the url and pass that in signUp API on click of submit button.
It's supposed to be a single transaction?

Thanks

Comment: Why not trigger a function when user clicks submit which will then first upload file to s3 then make the SignUp API call along with URL?

Comment: Thanks for reply Ninad, but isn't it's supposed to be a single transaction. for e.g if signup fails then photo will be of no use in S3, it would be just lying there. Yes, what I can do is check the status code of the signup function and delete the photo if it return an error. But it would have been good if it could have been done in single transaction. As of now, I would go according to what you told but let me know if you get a better design in your mind. Thanks :)